# Jenkins Build is not triggered with bit bucket web hook

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks, multibranch-pipeline

Trying to create the webhook in Bit-bucket for the multi-branch pipeline. I wanted to trigger the build whenever changes are pushed to bit-bucket. It's working for a simple and pipeline project, build is automatically triggered whenever a change is pushed. But it's not working for the multi-branch pipeline. I can see the request in the ngrok console and on the bitbucket webhook console with status 200.

This is my webhook URL `http://*****.ngrok.io/bitbucket-hook/`.

FYI: I m using ngrok tool to publish my local Jenkins to be accessible publicly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What triggers are you using in your coded pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me giving the URL as `https://<Jenkins url>/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify?server_url=https://<bitbucketUrl>`

Answer (score 0):

In Bit-bucket you just replace this one -- http://*****.ngrok.io/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify

Comment: I tried using http://*****.ngrok.io/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify still build is not triggered. I can see 200 in ngrok and bitbucket webhook console. Do I need to add any configuration change in Jenkins/bitbucket

Comment: In Jenkins -> configure -> Manage hooks -- uncheck this.

Comment: And  in multi branch Pipeline job, have you checked scan logs? Is it scanning?

Comment: And have u installed generic hook trigger plugin in Jenkins

Comment: yes I have installed the generic hook trigger plugin and Manage hook is also unchecked and in scan logs only loading screen I can see

Comment: Its not scanning the branches? and Jenkinsfile?

Comment: It is scanning the branches and Jenkins file only when I m explicitly clicking on  Scan Multibranch Pipeline, I can see the logs only when I clicking on  Scan Multibranch Pipeline.It's not triggered by webhooks. Do I need to add any other plugin on bitbucket/Jenkins